# After sending the data to the server, I get the message 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with sending the ajax request in php-script.

My jquery script selects some fields from form and sends as arguments to jquery function. BUT! After sending the data to the server, I get the message 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation'.

Example ajax

```
...
this.createOrderByKey = function(optionsData, customerData) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=module/pd_quick_order/createOrderByKey',
        type: 'post',
        data: {options: optionsData, customer: customerData},
        async: false,
        success: function(order) {
            console.log(order);
        }
    });
};
...
```

Example optionsData variable

```
var productOptions = $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea');
```

console.log(optionsData)

```
0: input.quantity
1: input
context: document
length: 2
prevObject: v.fn.v.init[1]
selector: ".product-info input[type='text'], .product-info input[type='hidden'], .product-info input[type='radio']:checked, .product-info input[type='checkbox']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea"
__proto__: v[0]
```

console.log(customerData)

```
Object {name: "Max", phone: "+7 (988) 014-07-77"}
```

Comment: A JS Fiddle of your replicated problem would help a lot.

Comment: Hm, i dont' know how to add my ajax script to JSFiddle... :(  I tried, but failed.

Comment: Select JQuery from the library dropdown menu on the left.  You will have to take out some of the irrevelant code in your original question - e.g. `this.createOrderByKey`...Just keep the `$.ajax` call that is in question.

Comment: Something like this... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/popovmaxim34/khf7d7m3/)
I have described the problem in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to solve my problem!

```
var options = productOptions.serializeArray();
console.log(options);
```

outputs

```
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your fiddle, theissue is in the `data: {productionOptions}` as you said.

The use of the curly braces here causes an error because you are not providing an object with key value pairs -with this use of {..} you are creating some sort of statement block, leading to the not invokable error.  Which is why when you remove the {}, it works.

As for your original snippet in the question, I don't see why it wouldn't work based on the above reasoning - is there definitely a problem when you use it as such?

Comment: So, okay.I rephrase my question. How can I convert a variable productOptions, to contain the [key: value]?

Comment: Thanks for the tip direction in which to seek a solution!